Azure PowerShell Runbook to export Exchange Online configuration and store it in a Blob
I have an extremely specific requirement. I am developing a Customized desired state configuration system. The solution will use Azure Runbooks to export Exchange Online configurations and save it as a blob on Azure Storage account.
For security reasons, all these actions must ONLY be performed via a Managed Identity.
I have successfully created an Automation Account and granted its System Assigned Managed Identity Exchange.ManageAsApp permissions; this works fine in using Get-, Set- commandlets towards the Exchange Online tenant.
I have also granted the same System Assigned Managed Identity Blob Storage Data Contributor permissions in the Azure Storage Account.
Storage account with Automation Account Managed Identity granted Storage Blob Data Contributor Role
This is the PowerShell script I use on the Runbook:
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity -Organization "empaysys.onmicrosoft.com"

$resourceGroupName = "CGTraining"
$storageAccountName = "cjdesiredstateconfig"
$containerName = "config-exchange"
$blobName = "Get-OrganizationConfig-withMI.txt"
$content = Get-OrganizationConfig | Out-File "Get-OrganizationConfig.txt"

$azAccount = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Pay-As-You-Go"
$azContext = $azAccount.Context

# Get the Storage Account
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName -DefaultProfile $azContext

# Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "Get-OrganizationConfig.txt" -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Context $storageAccount.Context

# Disconnect from Exchange Online
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false

On Test / execution I get:
Exception calling "Initialize" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

Could not get the storage context. Please pass in a storage context with "-Context" parameter (can be created with New-AzStorageContext cmdlet), or set the current storage context with Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount cmdlet.

Error on execution

It look like you are not getting any results so when the serialization code is called it fails.  What changed from when you used get/set until the current code fails?  Is it the out-file?  You may not have permission to save file in active folder.  Try saving on a shared file.


Azure PowerShell Runbook to export Exchange Online configuration and store it in a Blob]

Make sure you are getting correct file and also make sure you are providing correct context.
You can use the below full script which gets the configuration file from exchange-online and save it in Azure Blob Storage.
Script:
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity -Organization "xxxxxx744.onmicrosoft.com"

$subscription = "158b8345-c359-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f" #subscription id
$storageAccountName = "venkat891"
$containerName = "test"
$blobName = "Get-OrganizationConfig-withMI.txt"
$content = Get-OrganizationConfig | Out-File "Get-OrganizationConfig.txt"

$null = Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context  # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity
$connectionResult = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
$connectionResult

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "Get-OrganizationConfig.txt" -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Context $ctx

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false

Portal:

Reference:
Use Azure managed identities to connect to Exchange Online PowerShell | Microsoft Learn
